# How to avoid concurrent callbacks to user defined routine?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, autoit

I am attempting to modify some Boost code so that it is compatible with Autoit. The original project can be found [here](https://github.com/pdckxd/WebSocketAsioAHK). My version can be found [here](https://github.com/Danp2/WebSocketAsio/tree/dp_update). I could use some help in determining how to prevent multiple concurrent callbacks into the user supplied Autoit routine.

Here is the existing on_read callback --

```
/// Callback registered by async_read. It calls user registered callback to actually process the data. And then issue another async_read to wait for data from server again.
    /// \param ec instance of error code
    /// \param bytes_transferred
    void
    on_read(
            beast::error_code ec,
            std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
        if(EnableVerbose)
        {
            boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> guard(mtx_);
            std::wcout << L"<WsDll-" ARCH_LABEL "> in on read" << std::endl;
        }       
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        {
            boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> guard(mtx_);
            if(!Is_Connected) {
                return;
            }

        }

        // error occurs
        if (ec) {
            if(on_fail_cb)
                on_fail_cb(L"read");
            return fail(ec, L"read");
        }

        const std::string data = beast::buffers_to_string(buffer_.data());
        const std::wstring wdata(data.begin(), data.end());
        if(EnableVerbose)
        {
            boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> guard(mtx_);
            std::wcout << L"<WsDll-" ARCH_LABEL "> received[" << bytes_transferred << L"] " << wdata << std::endl;
        }       

//  The next section is where my issue resides

        if (on_data_cb)
            on_data_cb(wdata.c_str(), wdata.length());

        buffer_.consume(buffer_.size());

        if(EnableVerbose)
        {
            boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> guard(mtx_);
            std::wcout << L"<WsDll-" ARCH_LABEL "> issue new async_read in on_read" << std::endl;
        }       
        ws_.async_read(
                buffer_,
                beast::bind_front_handler(
                        &session::on_read,
                        shared_from_this()));

        // Close the WebSocket connection
        // ws_.async_close(websocket::close_code::normal,
        //     beast::bind_front_handler(
        //         &session::on_close,
        //         shared_from_this()));
    }
```

The code `if (on_data_cb) on_data_cb(wdata.c_str(), wdata.length());` executes the callback into Autoit, and I need to know how I can prevent this from executing more than once at a time. I am not well versed in C++ / Boost, so please be gentle. ;-)

Comment: Maybe use a `mutex`?

Comment: @PaulSanders The data would be lost if the mutex can't be locked, correct? I think that I should output the data to a queue and then process it from there. How could I process this queue so that there aren't any concurrent callbacks into Autoit?

Comment: When you lock a mutex, execution stalls if the mutex is already locked by another thread until it is released by that thread (I'm assuming here that your concurrent calls come from different threads).

Comment: @PaulSanders Thanks. I tried adding a mutex but I still got a crash in Autoit, so I believe that the issue is with Autoit's callback handling. :shrug:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gentle answer would be to point to the documentation: [Strands: Use Threads Without Explicit Locking](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html)

In reality you don't show enough code. For example, we have no way of knowing

- what execution context is being used. If you're using a `io_context` with a single service thread `run()`-ing it, you **already** have the implicit strand and a guarantee that no handlers ever run simultaneously
- what executor the IO object(s) bind to. In your code, the only object visible is `ws_` which we'll assume for to be something like

  ```
   net::io_context                ctx_;
   websocket::stream<tcp::socket> ws_{ctx_};
  ```

  Now, in case you want to have multiple threads servicing `ctx_` you could bind the `ws_` to a strand executor instead:

  ```
   websocket::stream<tcp::socket> ws_{make_strand(ctx_)};
  ```

  Now, as long as you make sure your own accesses (e.g. async_ initiations) are on the proper strand, your code is already safe. If you want - and you don't mind hardcoding the executor type, you can assert this:

  auto strand = ws_.get_executor().targetnet::strand<net::io_context::executor_type>();
  assert(strand && strand->running_in_this_thread());

> #### Pro tip:
>
> If you really commit to a particular executor type, consider statically binding that type:
>
> ```
> using Context  = net::io_context::executor_type;
> using Executor = net::io_context::executor_type;
> using Strand   = net::strand<net::io_context::executor_type>;
> using Socket   = net::basic_stream_socket<tcp, Strand>;
>
> Context                   ctx_;
> websocket::stream<Socket> ws_{make_strand(ctx_)};
> ```
>
> This avoids the overhead of type-erased executors, and you can
> simplify the assert:
>
> ```
> assert(ws_.get_executor().running_in_this_thread());
> ```

### Side Notes

- Instead of locking a full mutex to inspect a boolean, use `atomic_bool`.
- Use standard library features (`std::mutex`, `std::lock_guard`) to make easier better
- Consider building for the ANSI build, or check your widening approaches:

  ```
   const std::wstring wdata(data.begin(), data.end());
  ```

  is an antipattern. Look here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte or here for more information https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype/widen

### Demo

Obligatory "live" code:

[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b998c73f430e769)

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace net       = boost::asio;
namespace beast     = boost::beast;
namespace websocket = beast::websocket;
using net::ip::tcp;

static std::mutex s_consoleMtx;

static void fail(beast::error_code ec, std::string txt) {
    std::cerr << txt << ": " << ec.message() << " at " << ec.location() << std::endl;
}

#define ARCH_LABEL "STACKO"
struct session : std::enable_shared_from_this<session> {
    using Context  = net::io_context::executor_type;
    using Executor = net::io_context::executor_type;
    using Strand   = net::strand<net::io_context::executor_type>;
    using Socket   = net::basic_stream_socket<tcp, Strand>;

    Context                   ctx_;
    websocket::stream<Socket> ws_{make_strand(ctx_)};

    static bool const  EnableVerbose = true;
    std::atomic_bool   Is_Connected  = false;
    beast::flat_buffer buffer_;

    std::function<void(std::string)>         on_fail_cb;
    std::function<void(char const*, size_t)> on_data_cb;

    /// Callback registered by async_read. It calls user registered
    /// callback to actually process the data. And then issue another
    /// async_read to wait for data from server again. 
    /// \param ec instance of error code 
    /// \param bytes_transferred
    void on_read(beast::error_code ec, [[maybe_unused]] size_t bytes_transferred) {
        if (EnableVerbose) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(s_consoleMtx);
            std::cout << "<WsDll-" ARCH_LABEL "> in on read" << std::endl;
        }

        if (!Is_Connected)
            return;

        // error occurs
        if (ec) {
            if (on_fail_cb)
                on_fail_cb("read");
            return fail(ec, "read");
        }

        std::string const data = beast::buffers_to_string(buffer_.data());
        if (EnableVerbose) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(s_consoleMtx);
            std::cout << "<WsDll-" ARCH_LABEL "> received[" << bytes_transferred << "] " << data << std::endl;
        }

        if (on_data_cb)
            on_data_cb(data.c_str(), data.length());

        buffer_.consume(buffer_.size());

        if (EnableVerbose) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(s_consoleMtx);
            std::cout << "<WsDll-" ARCH_LABEL "> issue new async_read in on_read" << std::endl;
        }

        assert(ws_.get_executor().running_in_this_thread());
        ws_.async_read(buffer_, beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_read, shared_from_this()));
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. FWIW, I did include a link to the GH repo with full source code. It will take me a while to absorb all of your feedback. Thanks again!

Comment: In fairness, that's not part of the question. One cannot really expect people to go hunting for the question itself :) Regardless, I reviewed things and turned up some problems. https://github.com/Danp2/WebSocketAsio/pull/1 - The interesting bits are in https://github.com/Danp2/WebSocketAsio/pull/1/commits/e8c6b02347b8c1dcf36fe97a7f1ea708495b07a2